# Can I define begin and end on an input iterator?

Tags: c++, c++20

Lets say I have an input iterator type `MyInputIter` (which I use to traverse a tree-like structure) that satisfies the `std::input_iterator` concept.

Are there any reasons why I shouldn't define `begin()` and `end()` on the iterator itself?

```
struct MyInputIter
{
    // iterator stuff omitted

    auto begin() const { return *this; }
    auto end() const { return MySentinel{}; }
};
```

Reason being that I don't have to create another type just to wrap `begin` and `end` so I can  use it in a for loop:

```
MyInputIter iterate(TreeNode root, FilterPattern pattern)
{
    return MyInputIter{ root, pattern };
}

void foo()
{
    for (auto item : iterate(someRandomTreeNode, "*/*.bla"))
        process(item);
}
```

while also being able to use it as an iterator:

```
std::vector<TreeNode> vec(iterate(someRandomTreeNode, "*"), MySentinel{});
```

Comment: Of course, you can. There is already a type in the standard that models both `input_iterator` and `input_range`: [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://godbolt.org/z/Y1h1oncP3).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Are you sure that's an input iterator and not a forward iterator or bidirectional iterator?

Comment: @BenVoigt Forward and bidirectional iterators are refinements of input iterator. Hence, if directory iterator is either of those, then it is also an input iterator.

Comment: @eerorika: Structurally, yes.  Semantically, no.  An input iterator consumes the item from the data source -- it can never be visited again through the same or a different iterator.  Now, algorithms that work on input iterators will also work on iterators with a wider interface.... but the same relationship does not hold for software architecture/design.

Comment: @BenVoigt Another good point. In my case, multiple iterations isn't really the problem. I mainly picked input iterator because it's the most basic one that supports all the features I need and backwards traversal is a pain in this tree.

Comment: @Timo: Based on "backwards traversal is a pain" you probably want a forward iterator here.  It certainly matches my expectations for a tree-walk better to be able to save a copy of an iterator and be able to use it to repeatedly visit part of the tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any reasons why I shouldn't define begin() and end() on the iterator itself?

Potential issues to consider:

1. Implementing those functions for the iterator may be expensive. Either because of need to traverse the structure to find them, or because of extra state stored in the iterator.
2. It may be confusing since it deviates from common patterns. Edit: As pointed out by [康桓瑋](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11638718/%e5%ba%b7%e6%a1%93%e7%91%8b), there's precedent for iterators that are ranges in `std::filesystem::directory_iterator`, so this may not a significant issue in general. There is another consideration whether your range implementation works in an expected way.

> Reason being that I don't have to create another type

As far as I can tell, you don't need to create another type. You can use:

```
std::ranges::subrange(MyInputIter{ root, pattern }, MySentinel{})
```

Comment: Good catch with `subrange`.  I think since there aren't any major disadvantages I'll go with my initial approach, because it's nicer to use in the for loop. Also, I don't care too much about potential expensive copies.

Comment: @Timo: The major disadvantage is that it violates expectations set up by existing combination iterator-range objects such as `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` (or any other hierarchical collection iterator really) where `begin()` and `end()` return a range of children of the current node, not a range at the same level as the current node.

Comment: @Timo This is particularly bad in your case because your iterator is coupled to a tree data structure, so there is a collection of child elements.  The child collection is what a programmer will expect to access if using the iterator as a range.

Comment: @BenVoigt good point. Fortunately, in my case, it should be actually pretty easy to switch to that pattern.